# java polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism

Consider the following code:

```
public abstract class Base {
       public void getAnswer();
}

public class Derived1 extends Base {
       public void getAnswer() {
       }
}

public class Derived2 extends Base {
       public void getAnswer() {
       }
}


public class Main {

   public final int DERIVED1 = 1;
   public final int DERIVED2 = 2;

   public Base b;

   public static void Main() {

      int which_obj = which();

      switch (which_obj) {
      case DERIVED1: Derived1 derived1 = new Derived1();
                     // construct object
                     b = derived1;
                     break;
      case DERIVED2: Derived1 derived1 = new Derived1();
                     // construct object
                     b = derived2;
                     break;
      }

      b.getAnswer();
   }
}
```

here we are using a switch case to decide what object to construct and accordingly we construct it and assign it to b so as to use polymorphism.

what advantage is polymorphism giving us here?

Now is there a method by which we can avoid the switch case.
say: there is a mapping from int to String that returns "Derived1" or "Derived2".
given the string containing the name of the class. now can i construct an object given the String containing the name of the class. something like:

```
Base b = construct_obj(str);
```

the library call construct_obj automatically locates the class of obj from the bytecodes and returns a reference to the object. then i can avoid the switch case. typically i would be having 100's of Derived classes.

Comment: Did you mean "case DERIVED2: Derived2 derived2 = new Derived2();" ?  Otherwise there's no such thing "derived2" to be assigned to b.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could create a [`Map<Integer, Class<? extends Base>>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()) and then use `Class.newInstance` to create the instance with reflection. It wouldn't perform as well, and there are various errors which wouldn't be exposed until execution time, but it would work.

Here's some sample code.

```
import java.util.*;

abstract class Base {}
class Derived1 extends Base {}
class Derived2 extends Base {}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<Integer, Class<? extends Base>> map = 
            new HashMap<Integer, Class<? extends Base>>();

        map.put(1, Derived1.class);
        map.put(2, Derived2.class);

        int which = 2; // For example

        Class<? extends Base> clazz = map.get(which);
        if (clazz == null)
        {
            // Invalid choice. Do whatever.
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                Base base = clazz.newInstance();
                // Use base
            }
            catch (InstantiationException e)
            {
                // Handle exception or whatever
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e)
            {
                // Handle exception or whatever
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if you've got a contiguous range of integers, you could use an array instead of a map.

Another alternative is to have factory instances rather than using constructors - this would be "safer" (in terms of not deferring errors) but probably significantly more code. (In C# it would be easy using lambda expressions; Java 7 may make this a preferable solution too.)

Comment: This is completely valid answer and everything but I just have to say that every time I see Java that's not formatted by JCC rules it makes me cringe. One of those little things, you know, nothing important.

Comment: @Esko: Including 8 character indentation? Ick. Personally I don't think that Sun should have included formatting in the conventions - naming makes a lot of sense, as that comes out in an API, but I think it makes sense for different companies to decide their own preferred layout, especially as it's such a "religious" argument. At work we use the Sun conventions, and I've become somewhat used to them - but by and large I still prefer the "brace on its own line" style.

Comment: Obligatory brace humor: Some developers have argued [against this]. The author of this FAQ sees no clear advantage to adopting this approach and believes that said developers also put their curly braces on the wrong line. :-) http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#organize_1

Comment: Jon, quoting http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc3.html **"Four** spaces should be used as the unit of indentation. [..] Tabs must be set exactly every 8 spaces (not 4)." We don't use tabs at all at my work *(I think the reasoning was 'maximum charset compatability' or some such)* which means multiples of four everywhere. But as said, it's just something that hurts my eye in the same way as some people get annoyed if the word *Grocers* is missing an apostrophe.

Comment: @Esko: I do apologise. I could have sworn it was 8 spaces, which ends up being quite horrible. I wonder where I got that impression from. I still think it was a shame to specify it though :) (Oh, and I agree on the "spaces not tabs" issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You can call `Class.newInstance`

```
Class cl = Class.forName("com.stackoverflow.Derived1");
Base b = cl.newInstance();
```